# How do i create a field in my model whose value is calculated using values from other fields?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that takes in 3 integers as part of its fields

```
class TradeBill(models.Model):
    ......
    first = models.PositiveIntegerField(default= 0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(2)])
    second = models.PositiveIntegerField(default= 0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(2)])
    third = models.PositiveIntegerField(default= 0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(2)])
    .....
```

What I need to have is another positive integer field called `score` that adds up the value of the other three. Currently i just have it as this and thus taking care of it in the frontend:

```
score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default= 0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(6)])
```

But thats not great because i can put any value i want for example from the admin or any front end input i have. Sure i can do frontend validation to stop it from happening but django never let me down when it comes to their features so im sure theres something i can do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create additional field for `score` instead you can make `score` property of your model

```
class TradeBill(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def score(self):
           return self.first + self.second + self.third
    ...
```

**EDIT**
Extending the answer to include a serializer.
You can also include the property of the model in the serializer

```
class TradeBillSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       class Meta:
           fields = ("score", ...)
```

Also, you can use `SerializerMethodField` (as mentioned by [@Saif eldeen Adel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14162728/saif-eldeen-adel) in the comments.

```
class TradeBillSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       
     score = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

     def get_score(self, obj):
         return obj.score

     class Meta:
           fields = ("score", ...)
```

`SerializerMethodField` provides the flexibility to perform adding processing or formatting to the field.

Comment: interesting, so this property decorator will allow me to access an instance's score like `tradebill.score` but it wont be an actual field i can see in the database? And can i serialize this field/value/property normally if im building a rest API?

Comment: Nvm, realized i could just add a method field in my serializer to get the instance.score and store it in a score "field"